# how to insert input tag data-plugin in dom element?

Tags: javascript, html

how can i write data-plugin in "el" element in javascript??

### html

```
<input type="text" data-plugin="datepicker" class="form-control" >
```

### javascript

```
  // right cell
  var cellRight = row.insertCell(1);
  var el = document.createElement('input');
  el.type = 'text';
  el.name = 'txtRow' + iteration;
  el.id = 'txtRow1' + iteration;
  el.style.width = "100%";
  el.style.border = "thin solid #E0E0E0";

 // how to put in data-plugin="datepicker" in el ? 

  el.onkeypress = keyPressTest;
  cellRight.appendChild(el);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataset`:

```
el.dataset.plugin = "datepicker"
```

Comment: because i have not set "data-plugin" in my el yet

Comment: didn't you ask about setting data attibure to element? http://codepen.io/bora-89/pen/mPvxby

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsbin.com/ujiday/2/edit?html,output) you have an example took from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes.